# I'd like to make my app run better, will moving it from browser to node.js improve performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, animation, porting, p5.js

I am working on a game with my friend, he is drawing animations and other images and I am making code. The way I have been making it so far is through p5js library, but constant screen updating is slowing down the game as I add more and more things to the game. I counteracted it until now by optimizing it like not drawing things that are directly not on the screen or reducing number of collision points on player's sprite, but do all of my problems come from the fact that I am running it through the browser? I've read online that Node.js is an environment to run Javascript in, but I am still unclear how exactly this will work. From looking at apps that run through node.js like spotify it seems that they are able to run without real problems, although this might be bad example as it is not drawing something every frame.

tl;dr
I want my game to run better, will running it through node.js help with performance as opposed to running it through the browser?

Comment: Node.js is meant for running things on a server. It doesn't really make sense to run the display of a game on the server. You can look into more powerful game frameworks like libGDX, but that's going to get pretty advanced pretty quickly. You're probably better off identifying the places in your code that's causing the slowdown and improving those.

Comment: You might get better performance by moving your logic to a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) process, and keep the render process outside of the worker

Comment: Are you using `window.requestAnimationFrame` in place of `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a headless browser to be able to run your game code in nodejs. But thats kind of silly. You really want a browser to be able to play in. Did you debug your code and tried this [performance article](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Optimizing-p5.js-Code-for-Performance) on optimizing p5js?

Comment: Hello, I know this is a very late response and I apologize for this. After researching your page I was able to optimize the game, as it turns out tint function of p5.js makes everything run very slow. By simply not using it, fps rose dramatically. Thank you for your answer.